# Vercel.json redirect regex to match anything except files

Tags: regex, routes, vercel

I'm using Vercel to host a website and wish to create a redirect which will match any routes except the root or files.

My current `vercel.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "redirects": [{ "source": "/:anything", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

This matches all paths and redirects to the root, however it also matches files (which are all stored in the root folder).

The desired behavior is:

`example.com` > no redirect

`example.com/foo` > `example.com`

`example.com/bar` > `example.com`

`example.com/ANYTHING_THAT_ISNT_A_FILE` > `example.com`

`example.com/foo.js` > no redirect

`example.com/bar.css` > no redirect

`example.com/ANYTHING_THAT_IS_A_FILE.ext` > no redirect

Comment: Your example vercel.json is using `rewrites` but your question says `redirects`. Which one did you intend? You could try `/^(?!.*(\/|\/foo|\/bar)$).*$/`

Comment: Thanks @styfle sorry, I mean redirects but should be the same for both, will update the title

Answer (score 2):

Most frameworks support a [custom 404 page](https://vercel.com/guides/custom-404-page). You can can utilize it to redirect back to your home page when the requested page is not found.

Just add a `404.html` file with the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com" />
  </head>
</html>
```

The contents of this 404 page will redirect to example.com

---

Alternatively, you can configure [`routes`](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#legacy/routes) to respond with 307 temporary redirect if the requested page is not found.

Add the following to `vercel.json`:

```json
{
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    {
      "src": "/(.+)",
      "status": 307,
      "headers": { "Location": "/" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. The only caveat is that I still get the default 404 page on non-existing serverless function routes (e.g., `/api/(.*)`). Good enough for my purposes, but just passing along in case anybody else is having similar issues.